# Complex logarithm $\log(zw)\neq\log(z)+\log(w)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone help me out with explaining why
$\log(zw)\neq\log(z)+\log(w)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why $\log(ab) \ne \log(a)+\log(b)$ is because log is a multi-valued function. Just like $\sqrt x = \pm x^{1/2}$, ${\rm Log}(x) = log(x) +2\pi k i$ for any integer k. I.e. ${\rm Log}(x)$ is not one distinct value. To show why this gives us problems, consider one example;
$$0=\log(1)=\log(-1*-1)\ne \log(-1)+\log(-1)=\pi i +\pi i = 2\pi i$$
$$\log(-1*-1) \ne \log(-1)+\log(-1)$$

Answer (score 4):

Put $z=-1$ and $w=i{{{{{}}}}}.$

Comment: I'm not sure this answer addresses the OP...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am an [anti-psychologist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychologism). To me this is an explanation.

Comment: Hmmm...and I'm a skeptic...:) How does this even hint towards the "why" in the OP?

Comment: @DonAntonio ^_^ To an anti-psychologist the 'why' you refer to is merely psychological state of mind. A proof, no matter how little explanatory it might look, is as a good as an explanatory one, and I mean this not in mathematical acceptance, but in epistemological acceptance.

Comment: @DonAntonio: IMO, this very clearly hints towards the "why" the OP asked -- any dissatisfaction is because a person didn't want an answer to the "why" the OP asked, but an answer to a different, unasked question.

Comment: I can't see how it is towards the why, @Hurkyl. About the dissatisfaction: I can't understand why you meant ("a person"?)

Comment: @DonAntonio I think Hurkyl means that upon computing both sides of the equality, one realises that they differ by $2\pi i$ and that hints towards something, though that wasn't my intent at all.

Comment: @Git Gud: Then what was your intent?

Comment: @mike4ty4 My intent was that a counter example explains the 'why'. See my first comment in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

They will always be equal modulo $2\pi i$. The problem is that $\rm exp$ is $2\pi i$ periodic so you have to pick which logarithm you take, and you can't make a continuous choice on all of $\mathbb C^*$.